project file size during uploading to EAS build
I created a project with the expo and want to run eas build. but during the uploading of my project files to eas build my project file size was 161 MB.
It's my first time getting a build file from my project so I don't know if this size is normal, if it's not how can I decrease this size? or how I can build my project for android and ios.

A 161 MB project file size is relatively large for an Expo project. Here's how to reduce the size and build for Android and iOS using EAS.
Reduce Project Size
Optimize Images and Assets with tools like TinyJPG
Remove Unused Dependencies
npm prune

Check if Only Good Files Are Versioned
Ensure that only necessary files are tracked by your version control system. Review your .gitignore file to exclude unnecessary files.
Use Expo Asset Optimization
expo-optimize

Build Your Project with EAS
Build for Android
eas build --platform android

Build for iOS
eas build --platform ios

Ensure you have an Apple Developer account for iOS builds.
